# CQ5.5 Digital Assets Management Search tab not found

Tags: search, aem, dam

I am using CQ5.5.

I refer to https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/dam_documentation.html under category "Search for assets".

When using my super-admin account, i am able to see the search tab under digital assets. However, using other accounts, i am unable to see the search tab under digital assets.

I suspect it is a permission issue for different accounts, I may be wrong.

After a whole day of trail and errors, I still could not spot the permission to enable this search functionality in my Digital assets. Am i looking at a wrong direction?

Can anyone help me with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.